# array of associated product with price in asc order

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, configurable-product, product-collection

Code below gives me all associated products.

```
$this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts()
```

what should I do in order to get sorted valued based on price in ASC order ?

Comment: is this  configurable attribute??

Comment: Hey sourav, is this issue has been resolved

Answer (score 1):

This is sort of one way to do it.. But you'll need to make sure the price-as-string sorts alphanumerically the way you want. It may need some tweaking.

```
$sortedProducts = array();
foreach ($uesdProducts as $product) {
    $price = $product->getPrice();
    $sortedProducts[$price . '-' . $product->getId()] = $product;
}
ksort($sortedProducts);
```

Another is to use

```
$collection = $this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance()
    ->getUsedProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSort('price');
```

Note: untested code.

Comment: Unless you have 2 products with the same price ;)

Answer (score 1):

TRY THIS:

```
if($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable"):

  $conf=Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                               ->setProduct($_product);

    $simple_collection =  $conf->getUsedProductCollection()
                               ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                               ->addFilterByRequiredOptions()
                               ->setOrder('price', 'ASC');

    print_r($simple_collection);  // simple associated products collection

endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can be helpful:

```
public function getUsedProducts($requiredAttributeIds = null, $product = null)
{
    Varien_Profiler::start('CONFIGURABLE:'.__METHOD__);
    if (!$this->getProduct($product)->hasData($this->_usedProducts)) {
        if (is_null($requiredAttributeIds)
            and is_null($this->getProduct($product)->getData($this->_configurableAttributes))) {
            // If used products load before attributes, we will load attributes.
            $this->getConfigurableAttributes($product);
```

And in method **getConfigurableAttributes** you can see following:

```
public function getConfigurableAttributes($product = null)
{
    Varien_Profiler::start('CONFIGURABLE:'.__METHOD__);
    if (!$this->getProduct($product)->hasData($this->_configurableAttributes)) {
        $configurableAttributes = $this->getConfigurableAttributeCollection($product)
            ->orderByPosition()
            ->load();
        $this->getProduct($product)->setData($this->_configurableAttributes, $configurableAttributes);
    }
    Varien_Profiler::stop('CONFIGURABLE:'.__METHOD__);
    return $this->getProduct($product)->getData($this->_configurableAttributes);
}
```

Rewrite this method and replace **->orderByPosition()** with method you like

Comment: where rewrite can u tell , pls

Comment: For debug purpose you can try fix here. If this start working - make model rewrite. Tell me what kind of sorting do you want to add? Sort by attribute_label?

Comment: yeah i have attribute label size , i want to sort by size

Comment: Sorry my solution is wrong. Its another type of sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You can this.That can be an alternative solution.

### First get all child products ids

```
ChildIds=Mage::getResourceModel('catalog_product_type_configurable')->getChildrenIds($this->getProduct()->getId());
```

### Filter the product collection by those childs ids and short by attribute

```
 $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
 $collection
            ->addMinimalPrice() // optional for add minimal price to collection
            ->addFinalPrice() // optional for add minimal price to collection
            ->addTaxPercents() 
            ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes()) // add muitlple attribute to collection
            ->addUrlRewrite()->addIdFilter($ChildIds)->addAttributeToSort(AttributeToSort);
```

Comment: not works.......also why u used addUrlRewrite

Comment: mistake.... add addAttributeToSort for filter]

Comment: script stops some error still